# .NET Core + Openiddict InvalidCastException

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I'm using `openiddict` on a `.net core 1.1` project. So far i was able to login through `/connect/token` endpoint.

Suddenly, without any changes to the controller i get the following exception

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives.OpenIdConnectRequest' to
>   type 'OpenIddict.OpenIddictOptions'.

Is there anyone else having the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API changes have been introduced in ASOS 2.0.0-rc1-final that are incompatible with the exact OpenIddict version you're using. To fix that, remove the packages that start with `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect` from your .nuget\packages folder and restore your project when it's done.

Comment: For more info, you can see this thread: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/489.