# "Application is in Break Mode" with OpenIddict on .net Core 2.0 Win vs. Mac (scary)

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, .net-core, openiddict

I encounter a scary problem with OpenIddict on .NET Core 2.0.
I use a Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio 2017 at work and a Mac when I'm doing homeoffice. On the Mac I use Visual Studio for Mac.

So sometimes I continue work on my Mac, pushing changes to the Git repository and check them out on the Windows PC.

**Without doing any changes on the code that deals with OpenIddict** I am suddenly encountering problems **only on windows** when the code comes to return an access token through an AuthController method with this signature:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
```

The return command is

```
return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
```

I can debug until the end of GetTokenAsync(). Then the system runs into the following case and falls into the Application Break Mode.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'
>   occurred in AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions.dll

The project compiles fine on both my Mac and Windows. When I deploy to Azure from Visual Studio 2017 for Windows, the software crashes on Azure as well. When I deploy to Azure from my Mac, the software works.

**Conclusion: It must be a problem with Visual Studio or the NuGet packages?**

These are my used package references, they are pretty much up to date:

```
<PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection" Version="2.0.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Jwt.Token.Authorization.Server" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Mailjet.Api" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.9-dmr" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="2.0.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="2.0.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="2.0.0-rc1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.6.2" />
```

Does anybody has an idea, how I can get my Windows environment back to work? I even stepped back on my Git history to a point where I didn't do the last checkout from my Mac, but the problem persists. So I am pretty sure that it is a problem of .net core, NuGet or Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a manifestation of a breaking change introduced in the pre-release packages pushed to the MyGet.org feed we use (and that you likely reference). Remove the packages as indicated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715074/542757 and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Just found the solution myself. If you like, post your comment as a solution answer and I will mark it as the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting the contents of C:\Users\Me\.nuget.

@Pinpoint's comment points to the solution as well.